# Linux SSO for multiple windows domains

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, single-sign-on

I have successfully implemented SSO on apache for windows users in the same AD domain  that the apache server is in:
AD domain = example.com
Linux server = linux.example.com
KDC = ad.example.com

I set the KrbLocalUserMapping to ON in httpd.conf, as the application the users are logging into needs the @example.com part of the username to be stripped.

Now I want to enable the users from the branch offices to login to the application as well but they come from a different domain = branches.example.com. Both domains are in a trusted relationship.

When users from branches.example.com try to login they get "Internal Server Error" and apache error log says "Krb5_aname_to_localname() found no mapping for principal user@branches.example.com"

My guess is that users coming from the subdomain branches.example.com are not getting the domain part of the username stripped.

What do i need to change and where (probably krb5.conf?). Do I need to generate a separate keytab for the branches subdomain?

Also, since it is a production server which I cannot arbitrarily restart, what services do i need to restart after changing things in the krb5.conf?

Answer (score 3):

I've just hit the same issue as you, and thanks to [this thread](http://kerberos.996246.n3.nabble.com/krb5-aname-to-localname-issue-td21178.html) here, I've found the answer!

After turning on a second (trusted) realm in my `mod_auth_kerb` settings, and putting the right stuff in the keytab, if I tried to sign on with a user from the second domain I was getting errors in the httpd log like:

```
[auth_kerb:notice] [pid 1234] [client X.X.X.X:12345] krb5_aname_to_localname() found no mapping for principal user@BRANCHES.EXAMPLE.COM
```

The good news is, I've solved it! Details below....

Firstly, in your Apache HTTPD config, you want something like:

```
# Use this one for both Examples and Branches together
KrbAuthRealms EXAMPLE.COM BRANCHES.EXAMPLE.COM

# Strip the realm from the username
KrbLocalUserMapping On
```

That tells `mod_auth_kerb` to accept users from either the main domain realm, or the branches one, and strip off the realm from the username. That means that `admin@example.com` goes to admin, while `guest@branches.example.com` goes to `guest`

Next, assuming the MIT kerberos, you need to edit your `/etc/krb5.conf` file, and tell that how to map principals into usernames. For various historic reasons, this isn't done in a `libdefaults` section as you might expect. It's also not done on a per-realm section either, which caught me out. Instead, it's done with `auth_to_local` entries in the `[realm]` section of the default realm.

By default, the `krb5_aname_to_localname()` libkrb5 function will remove the realm from the default realm, and leave it there otherwise. So, we have to add an entry to tell it to strip the realm from the branches realm as well. (More complex rules are also possible, see the `krb5.conf` man page for more)

So, we'd want our config to be something like this:

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM

[realms]
   EXAMPLE.COM = {
     kdc = dc.example.com
     admin_server = dc.example.com
     auth_to_local = RULE:[1:$1@$0](^.*@BRANCHES\.EXAMPLE\.COM)s/@.*//
     auth_to_local = DEFAULT
   }
   BRANCHES.EXAMPLE.COM = {
     kdc = dc.branches.example.com
     admin_server = dc.branches.example.com
   }
```

Note how the `BRANCHES.EXAMPLE.COM` mapping rule doesn't live in its realm, but in the main `EXAMPLE.COM` realm, which is the default realm.

> Also, since it is a production server which I cannot arbitrarily restart, what services do i need to restart after changing things in the krb5.conf?

Just the Apache HTTPD service needs restarting after changes

Comment: Thank you! What costed me 5 hours to fix was a the missing 'lib' in 'libdefaults' m(

Comment: This also works with `KrbLocalUserMapping` set to `Off`, that way you keep the realm in the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable in your requests, so you can still distinguish which actual domain the user is originating from

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on @Gragravarr's answer (which works very well, thanks a lot !), if you had a `KrbServiceName PROTOCOL/domain.of.your.service` instruction in your apache configuration, you will need to replace it with `KrbServiceName Any` (otherwise you will get an error, because Kerb/Apache will check your ServiceName against each Realm...)